# MysqlDB - query is killed

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a python script which tries to dump a table with 7,5 mln rows but query after about 20 seconds is killed.
I use MysqlDB to connect with a remote DB. I read that MySQL --quick option could help as it does not cache each query result.
How can I use this option in my python script?

EDIT:
I used pdb. It seems that query is executed as all the 7.5 mln rows are present in variable "rows".
Here is my script:

```
def dumpDatasetToCsv(self, name):
    cur = self._con.cursor()
    res = cur.execute(self._query)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    column_names = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
    dumpFilePath=cfg.EtlConfiguration.exportDirectory +  self._dataSetName+ '-' + self.csvFileSuffix + '.csv'
    fp = open(dumpFilePath ,'w')
    myFile = csv.writer(fp, lineterminator = '\n') 
    list_to_export=[]
    for row in rows: list_to_export.append(list(row))
    for row in list_to_export: row.insert(1, self.csvFileSuffix)
    myFile.writerows(list_to_export)
    fp.close()
```

The code crashes at line "for row in rows: list_to_export.append(list(row))"

Moreover, when I used pdb and stoped executing script just before the above line then I just pasted the rest of the lines of the code line by line everything works. The output file is created.

Comment: I have not found `--quick` parameter into MySQLdb for Python but maybe you can do it using the `fetch_row` function which iterates through a table in order to dump it. [MySQLdb documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)

Comment: I edited my post. It seems that machine is out of memory but not on query execution.

Comment: Obviously it's due to lack of memory because your are trying to get all rows and dump them at the same time. To proceed with that huge number of rows, you must to process them into chunks as @user31415629 and me are saying to you.

Comment: @czyzyk14 The machine you are on probably has just enough memory to hold 7.5 millions rows once, but when you make a copy of them in the line where it crashes it runs out. Regardless, your approach will eventually fail anyway if the number of rows increases. For large datasets you should always be chunking everywhere, so that you only keep at most 1000 (or however many) rows in memory at once.

Comment: @user31415629 Thanks!. I will be experimenting with different fetchmany values but 10K seems to be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7.5 million rows is probably causing your memory to fill up and for the process to be killed. You want to be doing something like this:

```
with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as f:
   while True:
      rows = cursor.fetchmany(1000)
      if not rows:
          break
      f.write(...)
```